# Android Enterprise Solution

Tags: android, android-enterprise

I want to make QR code by which i enroll devices and when i want i can lock and unlock the mobile . During enrollment i also want to forcefully install one app that the user can't uninstall or modify.
Besically i want this for my shop when i sale mobile in EMI and when they don't give the EMI i will lock that device.

I have traid via Managing Android Devices Without an App but here the problem is only the apps which i enrolled in the policy is showing. The mobile defaults app is not showing. I want the device as default like the customer can't understood it's a under Android Enterprise Solutions. I thinks i am missing some policy .

And when i am doing using auth code. It's showing the error : `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/XXXXXXXXX/policies/<policy_name>?alt=json returned "Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise.". Details: "Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise.">`